# Test CLI with parameters

Tags: ruby, testing, minitest

I assume this is very newbie stuff but I'm learning Ruby by doing, and I'm developing a small CLI tool that receives a couple of parameters in order to do its stuff properly. This is my current workflow:

[image]

I want to test (using Minitest) all the possible flows:

- Exits with 0 and help message is shown if ARGV.count != 2
- Exits with 1 if first param is not correct
- Exits with 1 if second param is not correct
- Exits with 1 if both params are not correct
- Exits with 0 and does stuff if all params are correct

Now, if I run tests the only thing I see is the help output as there is no parameter being passed.

So, a couple of questions:

- How can I pass arguments to the main program in tests?
- How can I test the output? (I'm using `puts`)

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the `Open3.popen3` method to execute your file using bash, and check for the stdout and the exit code in your test. However, I wouldn't advise this.

Comment: Thanks Sander. Anyway, what would you advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice diagram!

you can either use helpers like aruba https://github.com/cucumber/aruba

or dig into ruby internals in order to bend it to your will!

```
# test.rb
pseudoIO = StringIO.new
$stdout = pseudoIO

puts "hi #{ARGV.join(', ')}"

ARGV.replace ["file1"]

puts "now its #{ARGV.join(', ')}"

abort "captured: #{pseudoIO.string}"
```

output should be

```
ruby text.rb "whutup"
# => captured: hi whutup
# => now its file1
```